# Retrieveing Twitter Tweet Entities Image's URL PHP

Tags: php, twitter, simplexml

I have this function to use the search API from twitter

I want to get the display image of a tweet.
The XML is displayed as this :

```
<link type="image/png" href="http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1625108559/meltaurus_normal.jpg" rel="image" />
```

how to i get its value out?
for e.g. `$image = trim($entry-> 'IMAGEURL' ?);`

```
function getTweets($hash_tag) {
    $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q='.urlencode($hash_tag).'&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=recent';

    //echo "<p>Connecting to <strong>$url</strong> ...</p>";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $xml = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $affected = 0;
    $twelement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    foreach ($twelement->entry as $entry) {
        $text = trim($entry->title);
        $author = trim($entry->author->name);
        $time = strtotime($entry->published);

        $id = $entry->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SimpleXMLElement::attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

```
$twelement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($twelement->children() as $entry) {
        $arr = $entry->attributes();   // returns an array
        print ("href =".$arr["href"]); // get the value of this attribute

}
```